# Passing object to objectdatasource insert parameter

Tags: asp.net

This is my object data source code.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    InsertMethod="InsertCustomerItem" SelectMethod="GetCustomerItems" 
    TypeName="HPPWebsite.HPPClasses.TestClassHelper">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustCode" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ItemIn" Type="Object" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="CustCode" SessionField="CustomerCode" 
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

This is my code behind:

```
<protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass item = new TestClass();
        item.CustCode = Session["CustomerCode"].ToString();
        item.ItemCode =" ";
        item.BasePrice =0.0;
        item.AddMarkUp =true;

        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CustCode"].DefaultValue = item.CustCode;            
         ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("itemin",TypeCode.Object,"item");
        ObjectDataSource1.Insert();
```

}

It gives me an error that type string cannot be converted to my testclass object. How can this be resolved please? I can do it if i just pass the object fieldds as seperate parameters but im trying to pass the whole object and do the trimmings and calculations in the stored proc